# GraphQL returning Dates as strings - how do I get them to return as dates

Tags: string, date, graphql, vue-apollo

Here is my GraphQL Query:

```
const { result, refetch, loading } = useQuery(gql`
  query {
    users {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
      createDate
    }
  }
`);
```

The createDate is coming back as a string.
How do I get it to return as a Date?